# access_token same as id_token when trying to acquire access token with ADAL.js AuthenticationContext?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am authenticating my Single Page App (Angular4) with Azure AD, and using Adal.js for the same. On the login page, I click a button that redirects to Microsoft AAD and upon successful login it redirects back to application home page, and receives `id_token` and user info from JWT.

I need the `access_token` for back-end API access, which I am trying to acquire through the the ADAL `AuthenticationContext`'s `getCachedToken()` method, and sending the clientId as parameter:

```
this.context.getCachedToken(this.configService.AdalConfig.clientId)
```

But this method returns the same token which is stored in session storage as `id_token (adal.idtoken)`. It basically creates a new item in session storage by with a concatenated key, which has same value as `id_token`

```
adal.access_token.key + clientId = id_token
```

ex: `adal.access_token.key239f6fc7-64d2-3t04-8gfd-501efc25adkd = <id-token-value>`.

I also tried to fetch `access_token` with `AuthenticationContext.acquireToken()` method, but it too gave the `id_token` back.

Where am I going wrong?

*EDIT: posting the code.*
I am calling the function `login()`, and after successful login, trying to get the access token in home page via `get accessToken()` property accessor in `adal.config.ts`.

**config.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  constructor() {}
  public get AdalConfig(): any {
    return {
      tenant: 'common',
      clientId: <application-id>,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/'
    };
  }
}
```

**adal.service.ts**

```
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { adal } from 'adal-angular';
let createAuthContextFn: adal.AuthenticationContextStatic = AuthenticationContext;

@Injectable()
export class AdalService {
  private context: adal.AuthenticationContext;
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    this.context = new createAuthContextFn(configService.AdalConfig);
  }

  login() {
    this.context.login();
  }

  logout() {
    this.context.logOut();
  }

  handleCallback() {
    this.context.handleWindowCallback();
  }

  public get userInfo() {
    return this.context.getCachedUser();
  }

  public get accessToken() {
    return this.context.getCachedToken(this.configService.AdalConfig.clientId);
    // return this.context.acquireToken(this.configService.AdalConfig.clientId, function(message, token, response) {
    //   console.log(message, token, response);
    // });
  }

  public get isAuthenticated() {
    return this.userInfo && this.accessToken;
  }
}
```

Comment: you should post your entire authentication code...

Comment: For authentication I am just creating an `AdalConfig` object with all the required info such as `tenant`, `clientId`, `redirectUri` etc, and then initializing a new `AuthenticationContext` using the `AdalConfig`, and then using the initialized context's methods. I have posted the method call. Please let me know what else is required.

Comment: Where are you specifying the resource you want to call? You need to post your code or no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: Posted the `config.service.ts` and `adal.service.ts` code, that's where I am specifying all the required info by AAD. Hope this will help :)

Comment: I think Shawn is on the right track :) I had a similar problem with ADAL.JS when I somehow specified the resource wrong so it got a token for itself (id token).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, after a bit of reading, turned out that connecting SPA's to Azure AD requires OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant flow. The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#single-page-application-spa) says:

> In this scenario, when the user signs in, the JavaScript front end
> uses Active Directory Authentication Library for JavaScript (ADAL.JS)
> and the implicit authorization grant to obtain an ID token (id_token)
> from Azure AD. The token is cached and the client attaches it to the
> request as the bearer token when making calls to its Web API back end,
> which is secured using the OWIN middleware.

So, it's the `id_token` itself that I need to send to the back-end APIs, which in turn can be validated and used. More info about validation is given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit#validate-the-idtoken):

> Just receiving an id_token is not sufficient to authenticate the user;
> you must validate the id_token's signature and verify the claims in
> the token per your app's requirements. The v2.0 endpoint uses JSON Web
> Tokens (JWTs) and public key cryptography to sign tokens and verify
> that they are valid.
>
> You can choose to validate the id_token in client
> code, but a common practice is to send the id_token to a backend
> server and perform the validation there. Once you've validated the
> signature of the id_token, there are a few claims you will be required
> to verify.

Comment: did you manage to get access token from id token using adal yet?

Comment: I am following the same method but calls to graph api returns an error 

 "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "",
      "date": ""
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

I've faced an issue like yours when I was trying to send the token to a .Net Core API endpoint.
It worked for me when I sent the token from the **adal.access.token.key** node, on sessionStorage.

Using **adal.access.token.key** or **adal.idtoken** token values (they are the same) didn't work for me.

[Valid token on adal.access.token.key node.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMz0D.png)