# Surprisingly I'm getting same code for access_token and id_token

Tags: jwt, angular6, access-token, adal, microsoft-adal-angular6

I have angular app version 6 and I'm trying to integrate Azure AD authentication and the micro services are in AWS.

Surprisingly I'm getting same code for access_token and id_token.
are they supposed to be different? my architect thinks so and asked me to tweak library to send responseType as 'id_token+token'.

What am I doing wrong and is there any way I can get access_token for sending as headers for api calls?
I have also attached the screenshot of the console errors of api c
microsoftadal-api fails
alls.

Below is my piece of code where I was trying to read access token for authenticating api calls.

```
enter code here
export class AppComponent {
loading: boolean;
constructor(private adalSvc: MsAdalAngular6Service, private router: Router,
private http: HttpClient) {
this.adalSvc.acquireToken('https://api.test.test.com/Dev')
.subscribe((resToken: string) => {
console.log(this.adalSvc.userInfo);
console.log('get resToken -->', resToken);
console.log('get oid -->', this.adalSvc.userInfo.profile.oid);
console.log('get accessToken -->', this.adalSvc.accessToken);
localStorage.setItem('accessToken', this.adalSvc.accessToken);
console.log('get token -->', this.adalSvc[enter image description here][1]
.getToken('https://api.test.test.com/test?userId=111111'));
this.configureRoutes();
this.loading = true;
this.http.get('https://api.test.test.com/test?userId=11111', {
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.adalSvc.accessToken,
'userid': this.adalSvc.userInfo.profile.oid,
'username': 'username',
'userrole': 'somerole'
}
}).subscribe(console.log);
this.postCall();
},
error => {
console.log(error);
});
}
postCall() {
const data = {
'dealerId': '111111'
};
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.adalSvc.accessToken);
headers.append('userid', this.adalSvc.userInfo.profile.oid);
headers.append('username', 'username');
headers.append('userrole', 'somerole');
return this.http.post(
'https://api.test.test.com/test', data, {
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.adalSvc.accessToken,
'userid': this.adalSvc.userInfo.profile.oid,
'username': 'username',
'userrole': 'somerole'
}
}).subscribe((response: Response) => {
console.log(response.json());
});
}
configureRoutes() {
this.router.navigate(['/dealer/home']);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have specified the right resource.

It's the id_token and not the access_token that you need to send to your backend APIs. Then you can get the access_token from the id_token.

It looks like you might be making the same mistake that the user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234519/access-token-same-as-id-token-when-trying-to-acquire-access-token-with-adal-js-a) made.